# Youtube Js Api - seekTo(time) takes a long to update the player.getCurrentTime()

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

When seeking to a time through the YouTube JavaScript API, it takes some time to the `player.getCurrentTime()` to return the correct time. It, instead, for some time, returns the old time.

---

Example:

-> current video time: 10s

-> `player.getCurrentTime()` -> returns 10s (correct)

-> `player.seekTo(2s)`

-> **`player.getCurrentTime()` -> returns 10s instead of 2s (incorrect)**

-> wait 2 seconds...

-> `player.getCurrentTime()` -> returns 12s (correct)

---

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also experiencing the same problem.  I'm not sure how it can be fixed, exactly, 
but I am working around it by using something like

```
  intervalId = setInterval( () => {
    var ytTime = ytplayer.getCurrentTime()
    [... do stuff here...]
  }, 500)
```

... which isn't optimal, though it works for what I need it to do.

I've put an issue up on the google issue tracker that tracks 'Youtube API Service' issues, here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142517061

but if I had to guess, this will be marked as a Works-As-Designed.  The call to seekTo needs to do some work to perform the seek, and that work is *probably* async, so when we call getCurrentTime before that work is done, we're going to get a time that seems invalid, but actually the task simply isn't complete yet.

Note that after you do your call to seekTo, if you did something like

```
setTimeout( () => { console.log(ytplayer.getCurrentTime()) }, 2000 )
```

then you'll probably be seeing the correct time.

Comment: You're welcome -- just to let you know, the google/youtube issue tracker has marked this issue as "Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)".

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Brian. I'm marking your answer as the correct one :). Awesome contribution to the community \o/